# How to debug user information in localhost with easy auth in app service?

Tags: azure, authentication, debugging, azure-web-app-service, localhost

I have a simple webapp in .NET6.  I'm able to authenticate users by deploying it to Azure App Service and follow through this guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-openid-connect) if I open the `azurewebsites.net` URL.

However, without the module in local environment, how can I authenticate / debug when the web app is running on localhost?

Comment: In Azure Active Directory => App Registrations => Your App =>In Redirect URI - Add Redirect URI for localhost as `https://localhost:portno/auth-callback`.Replace the portno. with your localhost port no.

Comment: From VisualStudio whenever the authentication succeeds, the authentication token will be provided to `auth-callback` end point on the local server.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your azure app service from localhost if the build copy is same as its deployed on azure.

You need to enable remote debugging option in App Service at below location
App Service-> Configuration - > General Setting
[image]

Then you can use `cloud explorer` tool of resp Visual studio get lsit of azure resource and accordingly you can attach debugger to app service.